# Is there a package or function that will make a reasonable guess at the mode/type/class of a vector?

Tags: r

Does R have some automatic type detection? Perhaps in a CRAN package?

The specifically, when R loads data (from a text file), it would be nice if R could make some reasonable assumptions about Types and/or automatically coerce them.

I know that you could *possibly* do something like:

```
try( as( x, "..." ) )
```

And try various types.  I would think that there is a better way.

Also, note, I am not looking to coerce into objects.  The basic data types is all: numeric, integer, character, POSIXct, ...

Comment: This is what ?type.convert does.  It does not apply POSIXt presumably because it's rare that time zone is included but you could do that easily enough.

Comment: `POSIXct` is really not a "basic data type". `read.table` (and friends) recognize basic data types (i.e., integer, numeric and character) by default.

Comment: @mdsummner Thank. I did not know about `type.convert`. It isn't exactly what I am looking for, but handy to know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am answering my own questions for book-keeping reasons, though the answer came in the comments from @mdsummer:

Use `type.convert`.  See `?type.convert` for details.